# Stack Interview Code methods made from class Node and Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, stack, pointers, namespaces

Mainly looking for feedback on my use of smart pointers to implement a standard stack. For interview level production code I have also include a namespace and asserts to test my class, let me know if that would be appropriate for an interview. I'd like feedback on my pointer management to avoid memory leaks, like how I have the option to use the classic `SomeObjectNameHere*` pointer to swap data in my `swap` function or the `unique_ptr` swap method.

Other than that I have taken feedback from all my previous posts to properly. Let me know what you think

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

namespace sonsprl
{
    class Stack
    {
        private:
            class Node
            {   private:
                    int m_data;
                    std::unique_ptr<Node> m_previous;
                public:
                    Node(int data, std::unique_ptr<Node>& previous) {
                        m_data = data;
                        m_previous = std::move(previous);
                    }
                    ~Node() { m_previous.reset(); }
                    const int data() { return m_data; }
                    std::unique_ptr<Node>& previous() { return m_previous; }
            };
            int m_size{0};
            std::unique_ptr<Node> m_top;
        public:
            ~Stack() { m_top.reset(); }
            void push_back(int data) {
                m_top = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(data, m_top));
                ++m_size;
            }
            void pop_back() {
                if(!m_top) {
                    throw std::out_of_range("ERROR: Can not pop. Stack empty.");
                }
                else {
                    m_top = std::move(m_top->previous());
                    --m_size;
                }
            }
            int top() {
                return m_top.get()->data();
            }
            int size() {
                return m_size;
            }
            bool empty() {
                return (m_size == 0) ? true : false;
            }
            void swap(Stack& other_stack) {
                m_top.swap(other_stack.m_top);
                // Node* other_top = other_stack.m_top.release();
                // other_stack.m_top = std::move(m_top);
                // m_top = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(other_top->data(), other_top->previous()));
            }
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Stack& stack) {
                std::string stack_string = "";
                Node* current = stack.m_top.get();
                for(; current; current = current->previous().get()) {
                    stack_string = stack_string + '|' + std::to_string(current->data()) + '|' + '\n';
                }
                os << stack_string;
                os << "---\n";
                return os;
            }
    };
}

int main()
{
    sonsprl::Stack stack;
    try {
        stack.pop_back();
    } catch(const std::out_of_range& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    assert(stack.empty());

    stack.push_back(1);
    stack.push_back(2);
    stack.push_back(3);
    assert(stack.size() == 3);
    assert(stack.top() == 3);

    stack.pop_back();
    stack.pop_back();
    assert(stack.size() == 1);

    std::cout << stack << '\n';

    stack.push_back(4);
    stack.push_back(4);

    assert(stack.empty() == false);

    sonsprl::Stack swap_stack;
    swap_stack.push_back(5);
    swap_stack.push_back(6);
    swap_stack.push_back(7);
    swap_stack.push_back(8);
    assert(swap_stack.top() == 8);

    std::cout << "pre swap\n";
    std::cout << stack << '\n';
    std::cout << swap_stack << '\n';
    swap_stack.swap(stack);
    std::cout << "post swap\n";
    std::cout << stack << '\n';
    std::cout << swap_stack << '\n';

    assert(stack.top() == 8);
    assert(swap_stack.top() == 4);

    std::cout << "passed all stack tests :) \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a quick comment: one thing you should try to pay more attention to is const correctness. Again, there are many member functions that should be const. If the function does not modify the object contents, make it const.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Overall

Not sure I agree with the use of `std::unique_ptr` inside of `Node`. **BUT** I can't really argue against it. So I am not going to push the point.

You need to concentrate on your const correctness.

### Design

Using a linked list for a stack seems very inefficient way of doing this. Each object that you save required an additional pointer. In this case were your data is a `int` you are basically doubling the space requirements (that's not including any overhead for memory management imposed by the system libraries).

The standard provides a `std::stack` class. This uses the `std::deque` underneath the hood (default) to store the data.

You should think about what it would take to templatize your `Stack` class. Storing `int` is good as a test; but there is no reason you could not store any object. Once you have done that there are a couple of extra functions that would be nice:

```
 void push_back(T const& data);       // insert by copy.
 void push_back(T&& data);            // insert by move
 template<typename... Args>
 void emplace_back(Args&& p...);      // construct in place at the back
```

### Code Review

I assume this has some meaning to you?

```
namespace sonsprl
```

---

Passing a `std::unqiue_ptr` by non-cost referece is a bit strange. I would normally expect that to be passed by r-value reference. When I was reading the `Stack` class below it confused me that you were passing a `std::unique_ptr` as a parameter without the `std::move`.

```
                    Node(int data, std::unique_ptr<Node>& previous) {
```

You are affectively hiding the transfer of ownership that the C++ community has tried very hard to make explicit and visible.

---

Both your destructors are us-less:

```
                    ~Node() { m_previous.reset(); }
            ~Stack() { m_top.reset(); }
```

I would remove both.

---

You could mark this function as `const`. I would not bother marking the `int` const (but it does not hurt). When you convert this into a template you should return by `const` reference.  `T const&`.

```
                    const int data() { return m_data; }

                    // I would have written like this:
                    T const& data() const { return m_data; }
                    //^^^^^^        ^^^^^
```

---

As mentioned above. I don't like the passing of `m_top` as a parameter (and it being changed inside the `Node` constructor).

```
            void push_back(int data) {
                m_top = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(data, m_top));
                ++m_size;
            }
```

I would have written it like this:

```
            void push_back(int data) {
                m_top = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(data, std::move(m_top)));
                ++m_size;
            }
```

This way I can explicitly show that I am transferring ownership of `m_top` into the `Node` and that the newly created object is taking the place as the new value of `m_top`.

---

There is an `empty()` function that allows users to check if the stack is empty before calling `pop_back()`. So also checking inside is a waste of time. If you really want to check then you should provide a checked and an unchecked version of `pop`.

```
            void pop_back() {
                if(!m_top) {
                    throw std::out_of_range("ERROR: Can not pop. Stack empty.");
                }
                else {
                    m_top = std::move(m_top->previous());
                    --m_size;
                }
            }
```

Note: the main use case is going to be something like this:

```
    while(!stack.empty()) {
        stack.pop_back();     // I just checked its empty
    }                         // are you going to check again?
```

If you look at functions in the standard library they tend not to throw (even if this would cause the object to be invalid). Instead the writters provide mechanisms to validate the pre-conditions of method so the user can do the check manually. Sometimes they also provide checked alternatives. That way a user of the functionality does not need to pay an extra cost (for the check) if they have already validate the pre-conditions.

An example of this is:

```
std::vector::operator[]std::size_t index)    // unchecked access into the container.
std::vector::afstd::size_t index)            // un-unchecked access into the container.
```

---

The `top()` function should be `const`. Your return value is **inconsistent** with the return type from `data()` (which returns a const). Consistency is king in programming.

Talking about consistency. The `pop_back()` function checks the state of the container (and throws if it is not valid). To be consistent the `top()` method should perform  a similar check (or both of them should not perform a check).

```
            int top() {
                return m_top.get()->data();
            }
```

Do you need to call `get()` above?

---

Another couple of function that should be marked `const`

```
            int size() {
            bool empty() {
```

---

Swap should be marked `noexcept`:

```
            void swap(Stack& other_stack) {
                m_top.swap(other_stack.m_top);
                // Node* other_top = other_stack.m_top.release();
                // other_stack.m_top = std::move(m_top);
                // m_top = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(other_top->data(), other_top->previous()));
            }
```

I don't see you swapping the size!!!!!!
Every part of the swapped object should be exchanged.

The normal pattern for this is to use `swap()` on each member.

```
     void swap(Stack& other) noexcept {
         using std::swap;
         swap(m_top,  other.m_top);
         swap(m_size, other.m_size);
     }
```

It's also nice to add a friend function so others can do the swap naturally as well.

```
     friend void swap(Stack& lhs, Stack& rhs) {
         lhs.swap(rhs);
     }
```

---

When printing. The value being printed is normally marked `const` (because printing it should not change it).

```
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Stack const& stack) { 
                                                                    ^^^^
```

Why are you building a string to output?

```
                std::string stack_string = "";
                // STUFF
                os << stack_string;
```

Just print each value directly to the stream.

```
            Node* current = stack.m_top.get();
            for(; current; current = current->previous().get()) {
                os <<  '|' << current->data() << "|\n";
            }
```

---

One late entry:

```
 return (m_size == 0) ? true : false;
```

You are using a bool test to decide which bool to return. Simpler to simply return the result of the test.

```
 return m_size == 0;
```

---

How I would have written it (apart from keeping the std::unique_ptr in Node).

```
namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Container
    {
        template<typename T>
        class Stack
        {
                struct Node;
                using Chain = std::unique_ptr<Node>;
                struct Node
                {
                        T       data;
                        Chain   prev;
                        Node(Chain&& prev, T const& data)
                            : data(data)
                            , prev(std::move(prev))
                        {}
                        Node(Chain&& prev, T&& data)
                            : data(std::move(data))
                            , prev(std::move(prev))
                        {}
                        template<typename... Args>
                        Node(Chain&& prev, Args&&... p)
                            : data(std::forward<Args>(p)...)
                            , prev(std::move(prev))
                        {}
                };
                int                     m_size{0};
                std::unique_ptr<Node>   m_top;
            public:
                void push_back(T const& data) {
                    m_top = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(m_top), data);
                    ++m_size;
                }
                void push_back(T&& data) {
                    m_top = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(m_top), std::move(data));
                    ++m_size;
                }
                template<typename... Args>
                void push_back(Args&&... p) {
                    m_top = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(m_top), std::forward<Args>(p)...);
                    ++m_size;
                }
                void pop_back() {
                    m_top = std::move(m_top->prev);
                    --m_size;
                }
                T const& top()  const {return m_top->data;}
                int size()      const {return m_size;}
                bool empty()    const {return m_size == 0;}
                void swap(Stack& other) noexcept {
                    using std::swap;
                    swap(m_top,  other.m_top);
                    swap(m_size, other.m_size);
                }
                friend void swap(Stack& lhs, Stack& rhs) {
                    lhs.swap(rhs);
                }
                friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Stack const& stack) {
                    Node* current = stack.m_top.get();
                    for(; current; current = current->prev.get()) {
                        os << "|" << current->data << "|\n";
                    }
                    return os << "---\n";
                }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, independent of whether a redoing a list here is a good solution or not. These days I would promote using `std::unique_ptr` in favor over raw pointers. Is there a case to be made against the use of one over the other ? 
This is not meant as flame bait, we all make technical decisions and this one still seems to have people a little bit puzzled.

Comment: Thanks I've modified my code! In your swap is there a reason you're using `swap(m_top,  other.m_top);` over the `unique_ptr<...>::swap`? In my Node constructor I am calling move internally, do I need to still need to have this call `new Node(data, std::move(m_top)` in my `push_back` function? I can not seem to get this new implementation to work with move used as a function parameter. Why do I not need my destructors?

Comment: How can I create a smart pointer without passing it as a parameter? Docs here note passing it as a param as you mentioned is bad practice https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp

Comment: `BUT I can really argue against it. So I am not going to push the point.` Did you mean *can't argue against it*?

Comment: @yuri fixed to can't

Comment: @HaraldScheirich I would argue that there are two places that we manage memory. Single item objects are managed via smart pointers. While multi item objects are managed via containers. Both of these constructs are designed to manage memory but we don't use smart pointers to implement containers as the containers are the method for managing the memory. Here we are building a container and it (the container) should manage the memory. Now as a beginner I can see the usefulness of using smart pointers in this context to learn other features. Hence I don't argue against it,

Comment: @greg In the constructor. I would use std::move to pass the m_top into the constructor. But this is because I would also make the underlying node take an r-value reference. Yes you still need to use `std::move` inside the constructor because even though the parameter is bound as an r-value reference a named value itself is not an r-value reference and must be made one by using `std::move`.

Comment: @greg The rule of zero is why you don't need destructors. The `std::unique_ptr` destructor will automatically be called and release its resources. You doing it manually is not required.

Comment: @greg Not sure what you are referring to on the MS page you linked.

Comment: @greg Update to show how I would do it (so you can see everything in context).

Comment: The second push_back is moving from a non-const reference to the data rather than a rvalue reference is that intentional ?

Comment: @HaraldScheirich No that was a bug. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

- `swap` does not swap sizes.
- If `pop_back` throws on empty stack, `top` shall also throw.
- I see no reason for an `operator<<` to build a string.

  ```
      os << '|' << std::to_string(current->data()) << '|\n';
  ```

  in a loop achieves the same result.

  I would also consider letting `Node` to output itself with `Node::operator<<`.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Node {
  private:
    int m_data;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> m_previous;
  public:
    Node(int data, std::unique_ptr<Node>& previous) {
         m_data = data;
         m_previous = std::move(previous);
    }
```

Since `Node` is an implementation detail of `Stack`, you don't need to hide `Node`s members `data` and `previous` from  `Stack`. Consider using aggregate initialization so that members can be directly manipulated.

```
    ~Node() { m_previous.reset(); }
```

Since the destructor isn't doing anything after `std::unique_ptr<T>::reset()`, it's equivalent to letting the class call the destructor of your `std::unique_ptr<Node>` member.

```
    ~Node() { }
```

Now, you have chained your pointers such that the current node is the owner of the previous node which owns the previous node and so on. When we call the destructor, this is essentially what is happening

```
m_previous.reset() calls 
 m_previous->~Node()
 m_previous->m_previous->~Node()
 m_previous->m_previous->m_previous->~Node()
 m_previous->m_previous->m_previous->m_previous->~Node()
 m_previous->m_previous->m_previous->m_previous->m_previous->~Node()
 and so on
```

And it's correct in that each node gets cleaned up and all the cleanup happens automatically.  Unfortunately, it's also recursive which means its bounded by the stack (memory) depth. To fix this, you'll need to iteratively remove elements.

Whenever you define any of the special member functions (destructor, copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment), you should consider whether your class needs the others. This is commonly known as the rule of five. By providing the destructor, the move operations are not declared. Normally, the copy operations are defaulted, but `std::unique_ptr` as a data member results in those being implicitly deleted. You'll need to implement the copy and move operations if your stack is to have those value semantics. The general guideline is that if you explicitly declare any of the special member functions, then explicitly declare all of the special member functions and explicitly `=default` (opt into the implicit behavior), `=delete` (opt out of the implicit behavior), or user-define each of them.

```
    const int data() { return m_data; }
```

`const` as a qualifier on the return type is ignored here.

---

```
class Stack {
  ...
  public:
    ~Stack() { m_top.reset(); }
```

Same issues as node, from recursive destruction to missing copy/move operations.

```
    void push_back(int data) {
        m_top = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(data, m_top));
        ++m_size;
    }
```

Avoid `new` and prefer `std::make_unique` to make `std::unique_ptr`s. It cuts down on the duplication and enforces consistency when you need safety in more complex initialization sequences.

```
    void pop_back() {
        if(!m_top) {
            throw std::out_of_range("ERROR: Can not pop. Stack empty.");
        }
        else {
            m_top = std::move(m_top->previous());
            --m_size;
        }
    }
```

Don't use `else` after language constructs that interrupts control flow (`return`, `break`, `continue`, `goto`).

```
    int top() {
        return m_top.get()->data();
    }
```

Be consistent with the naming. If directionality matters to you, then `back()` would be consistent with `push_back()` and `pop_back()`. `top()` would go better with functions like `push()`, and `pop()`.

Be consistent with your exception handling. If you throw on an empty stack `pop_back()`, then you should throw on an empty stack `top()`.

In order to modify the top value, the user has to pop (deallocate) and push (allocate). Consider allowing the user to access the top element by reference and modify the element in place.

```
    bool empty() {
        return (m_size == 0) ? true : false;
    }
```

`m_size == 0` will return a boolean that maps to the same exact values in your ternary. The compiler knows that and optimizes it for you, but you could help readers and just do it yourself.

```
    void swap(Stack& other_stack) {
        m_top.swap(other_stack.m_top);
        // Node* other_top = other_stack.m_top.release();
        // other_stack.m_top = std::move(m_top);
        // m_top = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(other_top->data(), other_top->previous()));
    }
```

You forgot to swap the size.

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Stack& stack) {
        std::string stack_string = "";
        Node* current = stack.m_top.get();
        for(; current; current = current->previous().get()) {
            stack_string = stack_string + '|' + std::to_string(current->data()) + '|' + '\n';
        }
        os << stack_string;
        os << "---\n";
        return os;
    }
```

`stack` is passed in as a reference. `operator<<` doesn't modify the contents of `stack` and can be qualified with `const`.

You don't have to convert `data` (`int`) to a `std::string` to stream into a `std::ostream`. There is already an [overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) that does this for you.

Do you even need `operator<<()`? A stack is a last in-first out container. Inspection only exists on the latest element pushed on the stack that hasn't been popped. This function also requires the inclusion of `<iostream>`. A static constructor is transparently injected into every translation unit that includes this header, whether IOStreams are used or not in the user application.

---

Overall, you should read up on `const`-correctness and `noexcept` specification. As for the design of your stack, I would consider splitting the management of the nodes (`forward_list`?) from the interface of `stack`, which could be adapted over an existing sequence interface.